# ssis - capturing the bad rows

Tags: ssis

HI, Can you help me to figure this out? Is there a way to get the row in which error occured in ssis? I have this flat file with some 10k + records which is being read via a 'flatfilesource'. 
Right now the error output defaults to error-column, error-code, and 'flatfilesourceerroroutputcolumn' - and i use a script-component to handle it. But none of these three inputs (to script component) are user-friendly enough. So i want to get an output like the first column-value(this is a unique identifier) of the row in which error occured. How can I add that?

Answer (score 0):

While debugging this in SSIS, you can add a Data Viewer on the path to where your script handles error. This path has all the columns of the original row where your error is.

If you want to handle your SSIS errors and also do something else with it, you can direct the error output from your flat file source to a Multicast and then send one stream down to a file, a table, or something else ( a Recordset destination and a subsequent foreach loop on the object used to store the Recordset will let you do stuff on a row-by-row basis on the errored row(s)).